# How can I explain magic theory in this scenario

Tags: magic

I have been trying to write a magic and fantasy novel and I always come across this problem where I am unable to explain the working of spells. For example, when a lighting spell is cast electrons from clouds are gathered by creating a huge positive charge upon the ground, but I am not able to explain how the magician can create a positive charge of the magnitude using mana.

note:- in this world, I have termed mana as energy similar to a boson aka the god particle(one of the subatomic particles) from the quantum model, it is in every atom and can be concentrated in the human body by the use of mind waves which can be made stronger by concentration, storing this energy lets you use it in a radius known as mind field(which depends on your ability to perceive the world), this energy can be extracted from any atom and can be used to break bonds of many compounds and also help the movement of matter, the concept of circles can also be added by keeping the particles moving in the circular path which will help to replenish this energy just like the movement of energy in the arch reactor of ironman, hence more no. of circles means more mana. I have used so many scientific terms to make this one a bit educational for children.

Comment: Don't explain; it's magic.

Comment: The physics and computational problem of keeping your balance while walking across the room are complex.  You don't  go into detail about physics or computation when characters take a walk.

Comment: The very idea of a $\rightarrow$magic$\leftarrow$ novel attempting to further the scientific education of children seems to come straight from the *Onion*. The first thing a reader must do when starting to read a novel featuring effective magic is to turn off all their scientific education. For example, "a boson" is any particle which follows the Bose-Einsteing statistics. All particles are either bosons (integer spin number) or fermions (half-integer spin number). For example, the plain ordinary photons (which carry the electromagnetic force) are bosons. Nothing god-like about them.

Comment: Sounds like you don't know much about subatomic particles. Don't try to use them to explain your magic. You will only make yourself look silly.

Comment: Please, PLEASE do not try to teach something you don't understand. If you're trying to get people interested in particle physics, getting everything wrong is a bad way to go about it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding! Just so you're aware, it's considered bad practice to award the green checkmark within several days or a week of asking a question. This gives people time to see and check your question out. Awarding the checkmark so quickly sends the message that you got what you came for and aren't interested in any more answers.

Comment: Explaining something is a writing problem not a worldbuilding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need to explain it. Just *magically* give an area a significant positive charge, and boom! lightning. The whole "mana" thing seems unnecessarily complicated, and remember that a) kids who are looking for an education on particle physics wouldn't turn to a fantasy novel, and b) kids who are reading a fantasy novel don't want an education on particle physics.

Comment: "kids who are reading a fantasy novel don't want an education on particle physics" <- You've clearly never met my daughters.  My oldest figured out by age 5 that the best way to get to stay up late is to start questioning the science behind her bedtime stories... the 3 little pigs takes a lot longer when you have to explain the entire manufacturing process of quicklime cement, how to lay out bricks so that the ones in the top of the kiln fire evenly with the ones at the bottom, and how to use a plumbline and spacers to make an even wall...

Comment: @Nosajimiki well, I'm sure there will always be counterexamples to anything.

Answer (score 3):

### Electrokinesis

Magic is the ability to shift the natural directionality of a force of nature.  For example:

Telekinesis is the ability to move Mass with your mind. Normally mass just likes to fall down, but with telekinesis, you can tell a brick to fall up or right or in a circle or what ever.

Pyrokinesis is the ability to control the directionality of thermal energy.  Normally a fire likes to go up, but with Pyrokinesis, you can make fires burn down or right or left, etc.  You can even make all the heat in an object collapse into a small point to start a fire or spread out to put a flame out.

So, what then of Electrokinesis? Just as a telekinetic can move mass and a pyrokinetic can move heat, an electrokinetic can move electrons.  While the default state of electrons is to move round and round in circles, the electrokinetic mage can turn that circle into a straight line just like a telekinetic can turn the straight line of gravity into a circle.  Because of this, the Electrokinetic mage does not need an electron gradient to influence random movements of electrons to tend towards the bottom of the gradient, you can actually move electrons in a whatever direction you want, even it it means going up the gradient.

So when you cast a lightning spell, there are actually going to be 3 electrical discharges instead of one.  The first is where the electrons are pulled from the environment, concentrated,  and pushed into the target, and the other 2 happen after the magic "lets go".  The second electrical discharge comes from the target and flows out into his environment in the form of a smaller series of sparks and lesser lightning bolts and the third, the least intense will be all the little shocks and discharges of the environment around the caster equalizing to make up for the lost electrons.

Eventually the whole system will equalize, but the only really dangerous part is that first discharge because the electrons have been compressed and set in linear motion as opposed to the mostly random and spread out wonderings of the electrons as they equalize

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think an important principle of magic concepts in worldbuilding is that they are built on the assumption that the audience suspends disbelief when interacting with it. I would argue that the most important part of magic is probably going to be equalization or normalization of progression and use (in other words, keeping one's ability to exercise it roughly proportional to reason).

But the idea is also that you don't have to *explain* how magic works - that defeats the very purpose *of* magic. If you were creating a text that was primarily science-based, with (potentially, to suit your scenario) one group possessing such great scientific potential that another group is comparatively clueless as to even the operation of such science, you wouldn't be talking about magic, you'd be talking about science fiction.

Comment: Spelling out how the magics works right in the text most likely will make the story worse. But having some kind of model how, when and why magics works just for author's sake can make the story better. It will make the world more consistent and believable, and limits the number of things that require readers to suspend their disbelief.